# How i can dynamically generate bower_components with bower.json using gulp

Tags: gulp, bower, frontend

I want to install dependencies listed in bower.json or package.json using gulp . 
NOTE : I have deleted bower_components folder and I want when i run gulp task to install bower.json dependencies . How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can you this gulp module : https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bower

It allows you execute bower commands such as install and update.

Comment: thanks for reply . But using gulp-bower I need bower_components folder. that is what i don't want . I want a gulp task which read bower.json and create folder having all dependencies